# When i add new datepicker dynamically the previous datepicker values reset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have form which contain **Add more field button** ,which dynamically adds new *datepicker's* whenever i click Add More field button.

The problem is ,Currently date field in the *datepicker* display the current date.
But when i add new *Datepicker* by clicking on the **Add more Field Button** , it adds one more *Datepicker* but this time it resets the previous value of *Datepicker* which i had set manually.

Below is my code:
html

```
<div id="container">
<input class="datepick" type="text"></input><button class="add">Add</button>
<input 
</div>
```

javascript

```
 $(".datepick").datepicker();
$(".datepick").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
$(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
    var appendTxt = '<input class="datepick"  type="text" /><button class="add">Add</button>';
    $("#container").append(appendTxt);
    $(".datepick").datepicker();
    $(".datepick`enter code here`").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());

});
```

Comment: have you debug the code flow? both datepicker must not share the same id?

Answer (score 4):

Because of this line:

```
$(".datepick").datepicker();
```

All inputs which have the class `.datepick` will reinitialize. You should do something like this:

```
$(".datepick").last().datepicker();
```

or

```
$(".datepick:last").datepicker();
```

after you add the new `input.datepick`. This was the simple solution.

If you have any other `.datepick`'s in another container after this container, this won't work too. You should be very specific about the appended datepicker element.

You should do this :

```
var appendTxt = '<input class="datepick"  type="text" /><button class="add">Add</button>';
var newInput = $(appendTxt).appendTo("#container");
newInput.datepicker();
newInput.datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```